# adb pair for Wireless debugging of Android phone from Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, adb, android-debug

I am trying to run `adb shell` commands on an Android phone from my Ubuntu machine. The Android phone (192.168.1.123) is on my wifi network while the Ubuntu machine (192.168.1.122) is on the wired network. Under the `Wireless debugging` screen, the phone has an option called `Pair device with pairing code`.

I am unable to run `adb pair 192.168.1.123:37795` (37795 is the port provided by device to pair with pairing code) because it gives the error

```
$ adb pair 192.168.1.202:37795
adb: unknown command pair
```

Tried using `adb connect` but it fails:

```
$ adb connect 192.168.1.123:37795
failed to connect to 192.168.1.123:37795
```

<strike>I think I am already on the latest version of `adb`:</strike>

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

What else can I try to run `adb shell` commands on the phone from my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I think you are using an older version of the SDK, since [wireless adb](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools#3000_april_2020) became available with version 30.x If you installed from distribution package manager (apt/apt-get) you may want to uninstall just to avoid conflict before installing from the Android Developer site.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I found out that my Android Studio has adb version 34. I am not sure how the one at `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb` was installed, its likely to be the `apt` package `android-sdk-platform-tools`. Created a new SO question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503400/which-android-adb-should-i-keep-on-ubuntu