# Which Android ADB should I keep on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools

I noticed that running `adb version` show an outdated version 28 on my Ubunutu 22.04 system. I'm not sure how `adb` was previously installed, maybe through the apt package `android-sdk-platform-tools`?

```
$ which adb
/usr/bin/adb

$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb

$ dpkg -l | grep android-sdk-platform
ii  android-sdk-platform-tools                                  28.0.2+6                                                       amd64        Tools for interacting with an Android platform
ii  android-sdk-platform-tools-common                           28.0.2+6                                                       all          Tools for interacting with an Android platform - Common files
```

Android Studio has a much newer version 34 of `adb`. Android Studio's System Settings > Android SDK shows `Android SDK Location` to be `/home/gv/Android/Sdk`.

```
$ /home/gv/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.3-10161052
Installed as /home/gv/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
Running on Linux 5.19.0-41-generic (x86_64)
```

What is your recommendation to fix this mismatch in `adb`? I am mainly using Android Studio and `adb` for Flutter development with Vscode. I am unsure if these changes can affect working on Flutter with Vscode.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You should probably state/show how you installed Flutter. But otherwise remove the old Android SDK tools, add paths/env variables to the correct location, and use flutter doctor to make sure that Flutter can find the correct SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to go to the place where you installed your sdk,

by default on ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS if you installed it with `sudo apt install`,

is **placed in** `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb` !

you should delete `platform-tools/`.
Go to android developer at

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

download latest version of plateform-tools et replace it anywhere you have it

in my case `/usr/lib/android-sdk/` > extract it > renaim it ' plateform-tools'
in final you have been `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/`.

`sudo apt update`  that's good !

```
$ adb version 
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 34.0.4-10411341
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
Running on Linux 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
```

Comment: This should be the answer for this question. I tried this and it worked. Thanks